# How to set font color for Excel header text using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, header, apache-poi

I am trying to set a font color of header text of Excel sheet using Apache POI. As attached screenshot. My code is,

```
    Footer footer = sheet.getFooter();
    footer.setLeft(HSSFHeader.font(footerFontName, "Regular") +
                             HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) footerFontSize) +
                             footerInfo);
```

How to set header text in red color using JAVA Code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Excel` provides special codes to format headers and footers. See [Formatting and VBA codes for headers and footers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers). The mentioned texts `&...` have special meaning in headers and footers. They are not printed but used to determine the formats. So simplest way is using those codes. Note `&color` needs to be `&Kcolor` where `color`is a hexadecimal value.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelHeaderText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelHeaderText.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelHeaderText.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  Header header = sheet.getHeader();
  header.setCenter("&C&KFF0000&24CENTER HEADER"); // &C = text centered; &KFF0000 = font color red; &24 = font size 24pt

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

This leads to a centered header in red font color and font size 24pt.

Some of those codes also can be set using [HeaderFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HeaderFooter.html). But `&K...` is not supported there until now.

Comment: Doing great!                                                       
        **header.setCenter("&C&KFF0000&24CENTER HEADER");**